Some default apps on 24.04 won't open with Wayland
I need to be to run on Wayland to be able to try out Studio One. But when I switch to Wayland some apps wont even open; settings, the file manager, the calculator etc... (the terminal works though) FYI I'm using a Nvidia card. Any help is much appreciated.

According to the official Studio One 6 webpage Studio One for Linux 6.6 public beta version requires Ubuntu 24.04 with a Wayland session. If not you could try installing Xubuntu 24.04 as a guest OS in VirtualBox. Installing Xubuntu which is a more lightweight flavor instead of Ubuntu will solve some of your apps not launching problems. To solve the problem launching Files you could try installing the lightweight Thunar file manager with sudo apt install thunar as a replacement and the lightweight galculator calculator app with sudo apt install galculator.
Studio One is a Wayland application and won't run in an X11 session. Wayland is a display server protocol, the successor of the X Window System. Ubuntu uses Wayland by default, but depending on the Ubuntu flavor you chose or your system configuration, you might currently run a X11 session. On the login screen make sure to choose a Wayland session. If there is no Wayland session available, install the required packages for the Wayland compositor of your choice, e.g., xubuntu-desktop. source

Studio one sadly just updated the requierements to 24.04 + Wayland... Honestly I do not understand why they would make it for a combination so hard to find and make work together. Anyway, I would've hoped that wayland just worked with vanilla apps in Ubuntu. Do you know any other flavours that run 24.04 + Wayland? Thanks :D

@Sune "Studio One sadly just updated the requirements to 24.04 + Wayland" Please provide me with a link to this comment, so that I can read more about installing Studio One in Ubuntu 24.04. As for flavors it looks to me like Xubuntu 24.04 is a better choice for this scenario than Ubuntu 24.04.

Here https://support.presonus.com/hc/en-us/articles/19214558269581-Linux-Getting-Started (Statement: System Requirements (updated):
Requires Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Requires a Vulkan 1.1 or OpenGL ES 2-compatible graphics driver

) Meanwhile Ill try out Xubuntu, thanks.

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 24.04.1 which preinstalled the NVIDIA 535 driver on my XPS 8960. Updating to the 550 driver resolved the issues, the Ubuntu 24.04.1 installation should now automatically add the 550 driver.

Thank you, this seems promising, I'll try it as soon as I get the chance. Cheers.
